# ActivityIndicator does not appear when I change the screen

Tags: react-native

I have a view with a list where there are 45 items to load with images. I would like that when you go to this page, a loading appears during the loading.

But the load does not appear. The screen freezes for 2 seconds before displaying the view

I use React Navigation with TabNavigator.
Among the menu, a button leads to this view.

I tried to put a setState but it doesn't work.

My code :

```
class Exhibitors extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return this._displayLoading(); // Simple Activity Indicator
        }
        // My List
    }

    _displayLoading() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I have the impression that my application loads the view before displaying the load.

Currently, when I click on the menu button, the screen freezes before displaying the view with the list.

I would like now that as soon as I click on the menu, the new view opens with the loading.

Comment: Can you create a codepen for this?

Comment: @ravibagul91 https://snack.expo.io/HyyxmirVH Latency is less present here, however

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ternary operator.

Usage

```js
class Exhibitors extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
        });
    }

      render() {
    return (
    this.state.isLoading === true ?  (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: 'center',alignItems:"center"}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" />
      </View>
    )
    :
     (
      <View ...
     )
    );
  }
}
```

**Example**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      loading: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  loading: true 
}));
  }
  render() {
    return (
    this.state.loading === false ?  (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" />
      </View>
    )
    :
     (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
       <Text>ActivityIndicator</Text>
      </View>
     )
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  horizontal: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    padding: 10
  }
})
```

Comment: Same result with ternary operator

Comment: @Mat Can you see the loading screen only?

Comment: Yes, if I only put the loading screen, it will be displayed. But I still have the screen that freezes two seconds before I access the view.

Comment: @Mat Does the screen stop before showing the indicator? Would you like to show that image?

Comment: I don't even see the load for a second. The screen remains frozen on the screen I am on just before.

Comment: What do you mean the screen stops?

Comment: I have two views. One with a Google Maps and one with a list. When I switch from map to list, the screen remains frozen for 2 seconds on the google maps screen before switching to the list screen.

Comment: Are you saying that you stop when you move from map screen to list screen?

Comment: No, the screen just stays frozen. As if the application was loading the entire view before displaying it

Comment: This video => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVsqEeZyBjE . I press " Exposants " at 00:06. The screen " Exposants " is only displayed at 00:08. Once the page is loaded at least once, I can access it without lag afterwards.

Comment: @Mat You don't seem to be stopping the screen, but you have a modal left.

Comment: Yes. But the change between the two screens takes too long. I can replace that with a spinner ?

Comment: You want to replace Modal with a spinner?

Comment: I would not like to use the modals. I would just like to display a load when I click on the button in the menu. And no delay

Comment: It's two different StackNavigator, so I can't use the modal.
The message at the top of the video is the one of the application that is filming.

My problem is that when I switch from a page to the "Exhibitors" page (exhibitors menu), it takes 2 seconds to display the page. I'd like a load.